# docker compose up failing to connect to postgres container on Apple Silicon Macs

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, prisma, apple-m1

Docker is not creating the postgres container. It is just creating the app build. As my app depends on the postgres the build is failing every time.

Here is my docker compose file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS7gl.png)

My Database URL: `POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL=postgresql://rohitnandi:postgres@postgres:5432/db1`

Error message:

### ` => ERROR [app 8/8] RUN npx prisma db push                                                        0.9s

> [app 8/8] RUN npx prisma db push:
> 0.822 Environment variables loaded from .env
> 0.823 Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
> 0.825 Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "db1", schema "public" at "postgres:5432"
> 0.864
> 0.864 Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`
> 0.864
> 0.864 Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres`:`5432`.

---

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npx prisma db push" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1`

For more than a week I'm stuck on this issue. Here is a github issue link which looks similar to mine: [https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10673].

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the Compose file and any other necessary information as plain text directly in the question, not an image and not behind a link?